Excel filter for tags
I have a large data table that is a catalogue of content. We have a column for level (beginner, intermediate, etc), a column for tags (where there are multiple applicable keyword tags), and multiple other columns.
I when using Excel's built in filters, the tags won't work because it shows every unique combination of tags instead of the individual tags.
Is there anyway to get this to work? I tried numerous VBA codes and I just can't get it to work! I want this to be simple for excel novices to be able to use on my team--otherwise I'd just do some unique search formulas when I wanted info.
Dim PreviousCell As Range

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim lastRowH As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim SelectedItems As String
    
    ' Turn off events and screen updating to reduce overhead
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    Set lb = Me.OLEObjects("ListBox1").Object
    
    ' Determine last used row in column H
    lastRowH = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRowH < 3 Then lastRowH = 3

    ' If moving away from a previously selected cell in column H, finalize selection
    If Not PreviousCell Is Nothing Then
        If Not Intersect(PreviousCell, Me.Range("H3:H" & lastRowH)) Is Nothing Then
            SelectedItems = ""
            For i = 0 To lb.ListCount - 1
                If lb.Selected(i) Then
                    If SelectedItems = "" Then
                        SelectedItems = lb.List(i)
                    Else
                        SelectedItems = SelectedItems & ", " & lb.List(i)
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            
            PreviousCell.Value = SelectedItems
        End If
    End If

    ' Handle newly selected cell if it's in H3:H(lastRowH)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("H3:H" & lastRowH)) Is Nothing Then
        With lb
            .Top = Target.Top
            .Left = Target.Left
            .Width = Target.Width
            .Height = Target.Height * 6 ' Adjust as needed
            .Visible = True
            
            ' Clear previous selections
            For j = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                .Selected(j) = False
            Next j
            
            ' Re-select items if cell already has values
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Dim arrValues As Variant, v
                arrValues = Split(Target.Value, ",")
                For Each v In arrValues
                    For j = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                        If Trim(.List(j)) = Trim(v) Then
                            .Selected(j) = True
                        End If
                    Next j
                Next v
            End If
        End With
    Else
        lb.Visible = False
    End If

    Set PreviousCell = Target
    
    ' Restore settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim searchTerm As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Set ws = Me
    
    ' Only proceed if H1 changed
    If Intersect(Target, ws.Range("H1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Turn off events, screen updating, and calculation
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    
    searchTerm = Trim(ws.Range("H1").Value)
    
    ' Determine the last used row in column H
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
    If lastRow < 3 Then lastRow = 3

    Set rng = ws.Range("H2:H" & lastRow)
    
    ' If searchTerm is empty, clear filter if present
    If searchTerm = "" Then
        If ws.FilterMode Then
            ws.ShowAllData
        End If
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' If AutoFilter not on, turn it on
    If Not ws.AutoFilterMode Then
        rng.AutoFilter
    Else
        ' Clear existing filter on column H before applying new one
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1
    End If
    
    ' Apply partial match filter
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="*" & searchTerm & "*"
    
    ' Restore settings
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Adding a screenshot of what you want will help decode the question better.

It may be easier to handle this by hiding rows, rather than using Excel's 'FILTER'.
Given an Excel file like this:

I'd recommend using a main VBA function
Sub FilterByTag()

Dim rng_TagCol As Range
Dim rng_RowstoHide As Range
Dim sTag As String

'Workbook Settings
sTag = Range("my_tag").Value 'Name the input cell 'my_tag' or change to hardcoded C3 or similar
Set rng_TagCol = Range("my_table").Columns(3) ' assumes tag column is the third column, edit to fit your actual data

'Reset the table so that all rows are unhidden
rng_TagCol.EntireRow.Hidden = False

' If blank, no need to hide any rows
If sTag = "" Then GoTo THE_END

' Loop through the rows in your table, indicate which to hide
cnt = 0
For Each cl In rng_TagCol.Cells
    If InStr(cl.Value, sTag) = 0 Then '0 means the tag is NOT in the cell
        cnt = cnt + 1
        If cnt = 1 Then Set rng_RowstoHide = cl
        Set rng_RowstoHide = Union(rng_RowstoHide, cl)
    End If
Next cl

'Now that the rows to hide are identified, actually hide them
If cnt > 0 Then rng_RowstoHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True

THE_END:
End Sub

Then you can just have it triggered whenever 'my_tag' changes.
NOTE: Hopefully this gets you started but you may want to add some more detail around the InStr(cl.Value, sTag) logic.  Currently, filtering to 'tag1' would also flag 'tag10' for eaxmple. Often, the tags will be separated by a delimiter such as a comma.  If so, then InStr(trim(cl.Value)&",", sTag&",") would ensure that tag10 does not get flagged  when the user enters tag1.

You'd have to be careful with this solution that one tag isn't contained within another - tag9 would return true for both tag9 and tag99.

FIND and FINDNEXT might also be faster than For Each depending on the size of the table being searched.

Good points - Darren.  Without knowing the OP's delimiter between tags, I can't code it in.  But hopefully the NOTE at the end helps give some direction.

I guess you could use TEXTSPLIT to separate the tags -  =ISNUMBER(XMATCH(my_tag,TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(my_table[@tags],,",")))) or my_variant = Split("tag1,tag2,tag99", ",") in VBA.
